# Debugging a JSON error from Golang

Tags: json, go

I'm fetching and decoding a large JSON response that has an error in it. Now I need to find **where** the error is! I [read about json.SyntaxError](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) but I am struggling to find out how to use it.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "text/template"
    "time"
)

type Movie struct {
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    PublishedAt time.Time `json:"published_at"`
}

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://s.natalian.org/2016-12-07/debugme2.json", nil)
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)

    _, err = dec.Token()
    for dec.More() {
        var m Movie
        if err = dec.Decode(&m); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            fmt.Println("Bad", m)

            // https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go
            if serr, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok {
                fmt.Println("Syntax error", serr)
            }

        } else {
            fmt.Println("Good", m)
        }

        tmpl := template.Must(template.New("test").Parse("OUTPUT: {{ if .Title }}{{.Title}}{{ if .PublishedAt }} was published at {{.PublishedAt}} {{ end }}{{end}}\n"))
        tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, m)
    }

}
```

What am I missing? Any tools or strategies or suggestions would be much appreciated. My output currently looks like:

```
Good {foobar 2016-11-24 16:17:12 +0800 SGT}
OUTPUT: foobar was published at 2016-11-24 16:17:12 +0800 SGT
parsing time ""null"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse "null"" as "2006"
Bad {barbar 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
OUTPUT: barbar was published at 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
Good { 1999-12-24 16:11:12 +0200 +0200}
OUTPUT:
Good {Something else entirely 2000-01-24 16:11:12 +0200 +0200}
OUTPUT: Something else entirely was published at 2000-01-24 16:11:12 +0200 +0200
```

But I need something like this in my stderr to **better debug the issue**:

```
Line 8: published_at is invalid
```

And maybe some context of the Title so I can tell the API backend team they have an error in their JSON response.

**BONUS question**: Furthermore I don't want to print the value *0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC* as it's actually really empty. I don't actually mind it being missing.

Comment: The error message tells exactly where the error is. *parsing time ""null"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse "null"" as "2006"*. In your JSON body, you've typed null as a string ("null"). Try removing the quotes around it.

Comment: I know there is an error there because I put it there. My question is asking how to print where the error occurred.

Comment: Have you tried the `json.unmarshal()` function? It returns an error if there is any that might help you, see [https://play.golang.org/p/eQCG-RE5sK](https://play.golang.org/p/eQCG-RE5sK)

Comment: unmarshall doesn't tell me what line it occurred on, and I think I need to use the Dec.More approach for efficiency.

Comment: Ah, it's not possible to get additional information, like a line number from the Unmarshaller or Decoder. There's a discussion here where someone has put together a "solution" https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/fizimmXtVfc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to both accept null values, and to not print anything if `published_at` is null, is to set `PublishedAt` field to a pointer value :

```
type Movie struct {
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    PublishedAt *time.Time `json:"published_at"`
}
```

---

The input string is valid *JSON*, so the json package does not raise a `SyntaxError`.

The `json` package has some other error types, such as `UnmarshalTypeError`, which is raised when an error occurs when the json does not match a nuilt-in type (e.g : `string`, `int`, `array` ...).

Unfortunately, when it calls a custom `UnmarshalJSON()` function, it looks like the `json` package returns the raw error :

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// check the full type of an error raised when Unmarshaling a json string
func main() {
    var test struct {
        Clock time.Time
    }
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(`{"Clock":null}`)
    dec := json.NewDecoder(buf)

    // ask to decode an invalid null value into a flat time.Time field :
    err := dec.Decode(&test)

    // print the details of the returned error :
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", err)
}

// Output :
&time.ParseError{Layout:"\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"", Value:"null", LayoutElem:"\"", ValueElem:"null", Message:""}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fhZxVpOflb

The final error comes straight from the `time` package, it is not some kind of `UnmarshalError` from the `json` package which could at least tell you "this error occured when trying to Unmarshal value at this offset", and the error alone will not give you the context.

---

You can look specifically for type `*time.ParseError` in the error :

```
if terr, ok := err.(*time.ParseError); ok {
    // in the example : Movie has one single time.Time field ;
    // if a time.ParseError occured, it was while trying to read that field
    fmt.Println("Error when trying to read 'published_at' value", terr)

    // you can leave the field to its zero value,
    // or if you switched to a pointer field :
    m.PublishedAt = nil
}
```

If you happen to have several time fields (e.g : `ProducedAt` and `PublishedAt`), you can still look which field was left with its zero value :

```
if terr, ok := err.(*time.ParseError); ok {
    if m.ProducedAt.IsZero() {
        fmt.Println("Error when trying to read 'produced_at' value", terr)
    }

    if m.PublishedAt == zero {
        fmt.Println("Error when trying to read 'published_at' value", terr)
    }
}
```

By the way : as specified in [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), "0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" is the zero value that the go team chose for go's `time.Time` zero value.

Comment: I quickly tried *time.Time in my struct but I still got "OUTPUT: barbar was published at 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"

Comment: ah, it looks like the parser tried to decode the *string* value `"null"` instead of a plain *null* value (`null` without the quotes).

Comment: btw is there is https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero ... nonetheless, it does suck how it's not easy to flag down an issue in the original JSON by line number.

Answer (score 5):

I found some solution:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &myStruct); err != nil {
    if jsonErr, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok {
        problemPart := data[jsonErr.Offset-10 : jsonErr.Offset+10]
        err = fmt.Errorf("%w ~ error near '%s' (offset %d)", err, problemPart, jsonErr.Offset)
    }
}
```

It will print something like

```
invalid character 'n' after object key:value pair ~ error near 'rence\","numberOfBil' (offset 14557)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data for published_at is "null", it is string type, so I think you can define the PublishedAt as string, and you can use code to parse it to time.Time.

This is my test code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/swanwish/go-common/logs"
    "github.com/swanwish/go-common/utils"
)

func main() {
    url := `https://s.natalian.org/2016-12-07/debugme2.json`
    _, content, err := utils.GetUrlContent(url)
    if err != nil {
        logs.Errorf("Failed to get content from url %s, the error is %v", url, err)
        return
    }

    movies := []struct {
        Title       string `json:"title"`
        PublishedAt string `json:"published_at"`
    }{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(content, &movies)
    if err != nil {
        logs.Errorf("Failed to unmarshal content %s, the error is %v", string(content), err)
        return
    }
    logs.Debugf("The movies are %v", movies)
}
```

The result is:

```
The movies are [{foobar 2016-11-24T16:17:12.000+08:00} {barbar null} { 1999-12-24T16:11:12.000+02:00} {Something else entirely 2000-01-24T16:11:12.000+02:00}]
```

Comment: I'd rather just try parse it to time (identify the err) and be done with it. What's with the unnecessary third party tools? But it might not be a string. Could be just null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like madness, but it should work:

```
rawBody := []byte(`{"title":"test", "published_at":"2017-08-05T15:04:05Z", "edited_at":"05.08.2017"}`)

type Movie struct {
   Title       string    `json:"title"`
   PublishedAt time.Time `json:"published_at"`
   EditedAt    time.Time `json:"edited_at"`
}

var msg Movie 

if err = json.Unmarshal(rawBody, &msg); err != nil {
    if _, ok := err.(*time.ParseError); ok {
        value := reflect.ValueOf(msg).Elem()

        if value.Kind().String() != "struct" {
            return err
        }

        for i := 0; i < value.NumField(); i++ {
            field := value.Field(i)

            if t, ok := field.Interface().(time.Time); ok {
                if t.IsZero() {
                    name := value.Type().Field(i).Name
                    return fmt.Errorf("field: %s, message: %s", strings.ToLower(name), "time is not in RFC 3339 format.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return err
}
```

This code will return first error happened. If PublishedAt is invalid we will know nothing about EditedAt even if it is valid.